# How to find the second largest element in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I need to know the way to find the second largest element among an array of objects. for eg.
if there is an array of objects of a Book class with attributes like book name, price, in stock quantity

```
Book[] b=new Book[];
b[0]=new Book("x",200,50);
b[1]=new Book("y",100,44);
b[2]=new Book("z",500,29);
```

How can we list the book with second largest price along with other attributes like name and in stock quantity

Comment: Well, there are basically two ways.  You can either iterate through them all, keeping track of the most expensive and second most expensive that you've found so far.  Or you can write a suitable comparator, sort the array, then pick the second element.  How about you try one of these, and ask for help when you get stuck?

Comment: PS : I would go with @DavidWallace's second option. :P

Comment: there's a third way which is as fast as a simple pass and is extensible to *k* and that is the **selection algorithm** which finds the *kth* smallest (largest) element in linear time.

Comment: Thank u all for ur rplies.. i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `List` of `Books` from it, sort it using `Collections.sort` and take the element on index 1.

```
    List<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<Book>(Arrays.asList(b));

    Collections.sort(booklist, new Comparator<Book>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {

            return o2.getPrice() - o1.getPrice();
        }
    });
    if (booklist.size() > 1) {
        System.out.println(booklist.get(1));
    }
```

Comment: How about adding some corner cases here? Less than 2 books for example?

Comment: as it is to find second largest number, corner cases does not matter. in case of two it would be either this or that

Comment: There's no need to convert the array to a list.  Just use `Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through this Array to find the largest and with this the second largest Element of the Array. Because the Elements are Objects you have to get the Value that you want to compare from the element with a getter or the variable is public in the objects.

```
public int getSecondLargest(Object[] obj){
    int length = obj.length;
    int largest = 0;
    int secondLargest = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if(obj[largest].getValue() <= obj[i].getValue()){
            secondLargest = largest;
            largst = i;
        }
    }

    return secondLargest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implements a `Comparator` And sort your array, then pick second element.

```
class BookPriceComparator implements Comparator<Book> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book a, Book b) {
        return a.getPrice() - b.getPrice();
    }
}

Arrays.sort(bookArr, new BookPriceComparator ());
```

Comment: +1 for knowing `Arrays.sort`.  This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should implements Interface `Comparable.`
2. and then use `Collections.sort();`

Comment: Please add more description to your answer. It will help questioner in grasping more out of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

//here you can make changes  or you can create your own new class 
//to sort book according to pages 
class sortPrice implements Comparator<Test> {

 public int compare(Test i1, Test i2) {

 Integer x = i1.getPrice(), y = i2.getPrice();

 return y.compareTo(x); //  <--- changed

 }

}

// in your case Test class could be Book class
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    int price , page ;
    String name;


    Test(String n , int p ,int pg){
        name=n;
        price=p;
        page=pg;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return  name+" "+price +" "+page  ;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int  getPage(){
        return page;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test[] b=new Test[3];
        b[0]=new Test("x",200,50);
        b[1]=new Test("y",100,44);
        b[2]=new Test("z",500,29);

        ArrayList<Test> a = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            a.add(b[i]);
        }
        sortPrice s= new sortPrice(); // required to pass as argument to tell 
                                      //based on which sorting order you want to  sort 
        Collections.sort(a,s ); //here we are sorting Test(Book) based on price.     
        System.out.println(a.get(1)); // printing arrayList   //<----- changed
    }

}
```